# Python suite test doesn't run tests

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am trying to code a suite test, I have one module which runs unit test correctly but I intend to add more modules and test them at once, so I have coded the following code:

```
#main.py

import unittest
from test.Services import TestOS

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    suite.addTests( TestOS.TestOS() )
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

TestOS.py

```
import unittest
from app.Services.OS import OS

class TestOS(unittest.TestCase):
    os = OS()
    def setUp(self):
        pass
    def tearDown(self):
        pass
    def testOSName(self):
        self.assertEquals(self.os.getPlatform(), 'Windows')    
    def testOSVersion(self):
        self.assertEquals(self.os.getVersion(), '7')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #import sys;sys.argv = ['', 'Test.testName']
    unittest.main()
```

After running it, I get this output:

```
Finding files... done.
Importing test modules ... done.

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 0 tests in 0.000s

OK
```

It didn't find any test, What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Include the code for your tests in your post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`suite.addTest( TestOS.TestOS() )` works only if your testcase contains a runTest() function.
Otherwise you need a "TestLoader" to detect the functions of TestOS that start with "test*".

```
#main.py

import unittest
from test.Services import TestOS

if __name__ == '__main__':
    suite = unittest.TestSuite()
    tests = unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestOS)
    suite.addTests(tests)
    unittest.TextTestRunner().run(suite)
```

Comment: I changed my code but still didnt run the tests, Are you sure it is correct?

Comment: I did test it, but I don't have the complete code of course. Maybe you need unittest.defaultTestLoader.loadTestsFromTestCase(TestOS.TestOS) ?

Comment: Here you can see it run on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/wWdmZ). Do you get any errors? Or does it just not run.

Answer (score 0):

modify your setUp method as follows

```
def setUp(self):
    self.os = OS()
    pass
```

Comment: Why would this make a difference? (The only reason it would make any difference is if multiple `TestOS`s are instantiated for the same run of the program and the OS actually changes between those instantiations, which sounds incredibly unlikely).